# Check for duplicate records while BulkWriteOperation into mongo using hadoop reducer

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, bulkinsert

I am using hadoop map-reduce for processing XML file. I am directly storing the JSON data into mongodb.
 How can I achieve that only non-duplicate records will be stored into database before executing `BulkWriteOperation`?

The duplicate records **criteria will be based on product image and product name**, I do not want to use a **layer of morphia** where we can assign indexes to the class members.

Here is my reducer class:

```
public class XMLReducer extends Reducer<Text, MapWritable, Text, NullWritable>{

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(XMLReducer.class);    

protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<MapWritable> values, Context ctx) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    LOGGER.info("reduce()------Start for key>"+key);
    Map<String,String> insertProductInfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
    try{
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
        BulkWriteOperation operation = db.getCollection("product").initializeOrderedBulkOperation();
        for (MapWritable entry : values) {
             for (Entry<Writable, Writable> extractProductInfo : entry.entrySet()) {
                    insertProductInfo.put(extractProductInfo.getKey().toString(), extractProductInfo.getValue().toString());
                }
             if(!insertProductInfo.isEmpty()){
                 BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject(insertProductInfo);
                 operation.insert(basicDBObject);
             }          
        }
        //How can I check for duplicates before executing bulk operation
        operation.execute();
        LOGGER.info("reduce------end for key"+key);
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.error("General Exception in XMLReducer",e);
    }
  } 
}
```

**EDIT:** After the suggested answer I have added :

```
 BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("product_image", basicDBObject.get("product_image"))
                 .append("product_name", basicDBObject.get("product_name"));
                 operation.find(query).upsert().updateOne(new BasicDBObject("$setOnInsert", basicDBObject));
 operation.insert(basicDBObject);
```

I am getting error like: `com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: no mapping found for index 0`

Any help will be useful.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it all depends on what you really want to do with the "duplicates" here as to how you handle it.

For one you can always use [**`.initializeUnOrderedBulkOperation()`**](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.13/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#initializeUnorderedBulkOperation--) which won't "error" on a duplicate key from your index ( which you need to stop duplicates ) but will report any such errors in the returned [**`BulkWriteResult`**](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.13/com/mongodb/BulkWriteResult.html) object. Which is returned from `.execute()`

```
BulkWriteResult result = operation.execute();
```

On the other hand, you can just use "upserts" instead and use operators such as [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) to only make changes where no duplicate existed:

```
BasicDBObject basicdbobject = new BasicDBObject(insertProductInfo);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("key", basicdbobject.get("key"));

operation.find(query).upsert().updateOne(new BasicDBObject("$setOnInsert", basicdbobject));
```

So you basically look up the value of the field that holds the "key" to determine a duplicate with a query, then only actually change any data where that "key" was not found and therefore a new document and "inserted".

In either case the default behaviour here will be to "insert" the first unique "key" value and then ignore all other occurances. If you want to do other things like "overwrite" or "increment" values where the same key is found then the `.update()` "upsert" approach is the one you want, but you will use other [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/) for those actions.

Comment: I am not getting how should I create a query? I want to check if `basicdbobject` containing  `insertProductInfo`  having many fileds. From that  product name and product image is my criteria for checking duplicate records if that is present in operation or not?

Comment: @Nakul91 There should only be a "finite" number of fields that truly form a duplicate. Then again if the whole content is never supposed to exist more than once, then just use the object you are inserting as the query in full. If you are really unsure then ask another question. But you should have a "unique" index defined on the fields you consider "unique".

Comment: The uniqueness is defined on these two fields only. I have added compound index on these fields on collection but when doing bulk insert using  .initializeUnOrderedBulkOperation() for say 5000 records if 1001th record is duplicate then it throws exception and remaining 4000 records are not getting added into db.  According to you it wont error on duplicate but still it is giving an error

Comment: @Nakul91 Not if you are using an "update" on the unique fields as shown. an `.insert()` operation can throw a duplicate key error. Searching for the unique properties and using `.update()` "overwrites" or more specifically "does nothing" due to `$setOnInsert`. If you are getting duplicate key errors you are not querying on **all** the unique values.

Comment: @Nakul91 The answer I have already given cannot be more clear. You "query" on the "unique" fields of your document and an `.update()` operation "cannot possibly" produce a duplicate. The answer is correct, but your coding seems to be at fault. Please post another question for any further difficulties you have if you still cannot understand. There will be no more correspondance on this answer as it is completely correct within itself.

Comment: Thanks, After checking many times I found that I am doing a silly mistake. I was updating as well inserting doing both in bulkoperation. :) Thanks for the help and your time!